# Can UIColor be initialised with both dark and light mode color?

Tags: swift, uiview, uicolor

I am using random pastel colours in my training app (bouncing circles), but when my iPad is in dark mode, the pastels looks very bland. Can I somehow initialise UIColor with two colours? Maybe something like:

```
UIColor(forLightMode: UIColor, forDarkMode: UIColor)
```

My current app is creating new colours properly, but they do not change automatically, when I change from dark to light mode. The app is just starting to generate new ones from `pastel` set.

```
func makeRandomColor() -> UIColor {

    let fullRange : ClosedRange<CGFloat> = 0...255
    let pastelRange : ClosedRange<CGFloat> = 127...255

    let randomPastelRed     = CGFloat.random(in: pastelRange) / 255
    let randomPastelGreen   = CGFloat.random(in: pastelRange) / 255
    let randomPastelBlue    = CGFloat.random(in: pastelRange) / 255

    let randomRed           = CGFloat.random(in: fullRange) / 255
    let randomGreen         = CGFloat.random(in: fullRange) / 255
    let randomBlue          = CGFloat.random(in: fullRange) / 255

    let randomAlpha         = CGFloat.random(in: 0.6...1)

    return UIColor.init(dynamicProvider: { traitCollection in
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            return UIColor(
                red: randomRed,
                green: randomGreen,
                blue: randomBlue,
                alpha: randomAlpha
            )
        } else {
            return UIColor(
                red: randomPastelRed,
                green: randomPastelGreen,
                blue: randomPastelBlue,
                alpha: randomAlpha
            )
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var dynamicColor =  UIColor {(traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
    if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        return .white
    } else {
        return .black
    }
}
```

Taken from a Screencast course on Ray Wenderlich (I'm not affiliated with the website): https://www.raywenderlich.com/3979883-dark-mode-deep-dive

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to listen to `traitCollectionDidChange` notification and redraw your UI either by calling `setNeedsLayout()` or similar methods from your `UIView` or `UIViewController`. For more Information check [Implementing Dark Mode on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/) ~22min